# Get a list of google apps users by domain

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, google-apps

I have a business google account in my organization. I would like to programmatically query the users of my domain from the google API. The usage is for a service that runs every now and then, without any human interaction (meaning - no UI).

In the normal flow I would have to create a google app and let users allow it for their accounts. Because I'm using a service, I'm looking to do some REST call that would return the data. Is there a way for me to create generic credentials for use in the code without users need to approve anything?

The API I want to use is:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add your app to the API Client access pane in cpanel: https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en

Comment: That's the issue. I don't have an app. That's a business domain and I want to query the users in our domain for an internal tool.

Comment: What's the difference between your domain and a business domain?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand it enough, but the thing is - I don't have an app. You mentioned that I need to add my app, which I don't have....

Comment: Ok, I understand. Do you have a Google Apps for Work domain, and do you have a superadmin account for that domain?

Comment: I have google apps for work. Not sure if I have a super account, but I can create it if that's the way :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120456/discussion-between-abrahamb-and-avi).